# Can two thread access two different static method of same class

Tags: java, multithreading

Can two thread access two different static method of same class at the same time?

```
class A {

public static void m1(){
System.out.println("inside m1");

}
public static void m2(){
System.out.println("inside m2");
}
}
```

and created two threads t1 and t2

Comment: Yes they can <!-->

Comment: Yes, multiple threads could even access the *same* `static` method in the same class at the same time, unless that method is `synchronized`. Running a method essentially boils down to a thread executing byte instructions stored in a classfile, anything could read and execute those instructions no problem (except when you have something on the VM level stopping them, like synchronization or locks). The danger comes when you read/write data.

Comment: Of course they can, but *should* they? That entirely depends on what the methods are doing. If the methods access shared data (state), then the answer is no (unless you synchronize the methods or otherwise protect them with locks).

Comment: they can, but you can hardly guarantee that it will happen at the same time (e.g. running on one cpu/core)

Comment: You really are asking the wrong question. You should not be worried about whether different threads call the same methods at the same time, or whether they call methods belonging to the same class at the same time. You should be worried about whether multiple threads access the same _mutable data_ at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can. None of two methods in your class are synchronized, it means that there will be no lock of class' monitor and any threads will be able to execute any methods simultaneously.